# Linear function with live data

Tags: function, numpy, linear-algebra

I am an absolute newbie on the programming thing and really desperate. I picked up a high end task to solve as it seems to me...

I know there are tons of explanations for solving y = mx + b with python but they're all for the situation with "solid" data. I am trying to realize it with live data.

So far, i have two data streams, which I successful directed into two lists - please see code below.

```
for graph in basis_graph:

    high_1 = float(graph.high)
    low_1 = float(graph.low)

    if high_1 > 0:
        graph_high.append([high_1])
    if low_1 > 0:
        graph_low.append([low_1])
```

Now comes the tricky part and I DON`T GET IT. I need a function that calculates me "m". Something like that:

```
def function_signal():
    if graph_high[-1] < graph_high[-2]:
       please, mr. computer, calculate me "m"
```

I tried something like

```
    def signal():
        if graph_low[-1] < graph_low[-2]:
            print("a")
            ay1 = graph_low[-1]
            by1 = graph_low[-2]
            m = ay1 - by1
            return m
        print(m(ay1, ay2))
```

Two days I tried EVERYTHING from what I know so far but the only thing I earned was a cascade of Tracebacks. From "I can't divide two list objects" to " "m" is not defined" and so on and so on...

In the case above for example NOTHING happens. Sometimes he says "m is not defined"...

Please, if there's someone out there who is willing to help me than I would really appreciate it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In `graph_high.append([high_1])` you are creating a nested list: `high_1` is a list of lists, where the inner lists have length 1. You probably want `graph_high.append(high_1)`. With the tracebacks we can only help you if you provide the actual code.

Comment: @Feodoran Thank you for the note. I've edited the code. And I've edited the question so that my issue is more clear...I do hope so.

Comment: There are a number of possible issues here. Can please provide complete code, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example